# Rails nested attributes passing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following definition:

```
params.require(:sets).permit(:name, zones_attributes: [:latitude, :longitude])
```

And i would like to send them by ajax with jQuery, thing is I think i'm constructing it wrong because I keep getting this error:

> Unpermitted parameters: 0, 1

This is what I'm sending:

```
{
"sets"=>{
    "name"=>"America", 
    "zones_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>[
            "49.95121990866204", 
            "-117.861328125"
         ], 
         "1"=>[
            "-33.578014746143985", 
            "-55.986328125"
          ]
       }
    }, 
    "action"=>"create", 
    "controller"=>"sets"
}
```

I think the problem is the "key" value being added before the latitude/longitude value.
This is how I'm adding those values:

```
  this.zones.push([marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng()]);
```

Is there a way to add them without the keys? Or am I going through the wrong way?

*UPDATE*

ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/zone_sets',
        data: { zone_sets: { name: map.markerListName ,zones_attributes: map.zones } },
        success: function (data) { $("input[name=zone_set]").append(data) },
      });
```

Comment: It's what i print in my question after 'This is what i'm sending'

Comment: sorry, just realized ^

Comment: why don't they have keys? Could you post the code for your form? Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for`? Are you using `fields_for`?

Comment: @WhomWhomWhom could you add full `ajax` code?

Comment: @WhomWhomWhom attach ajax or form, how triggering it.

Comment: I do have accepts_nested_attributes_for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your current `ajax` code to:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      url: '/zone_sets',
      data: JSON.stringify({ zone_sets: { name: map.markerListName ,zones_attributes: map.zones } }),
        success: function (data) { $("input[name=zone_set]").append(data) },
    });
```

As you can see the actual problem is how the Rails handle and parse a request.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding them like this:

```
this.zones.push({'latitude': marker.position.lat(), 'longitude': marker.position.lng()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "key" looks like it's the problem.

`params.require(:sets).permit(:name, zones_attributes: [:latitude, :longitude])` is expecting your request to be in the format:

```
{
"sets"=>{
    "name"=>"America", 
    "zones_attributes"=>[
     {
        "latitude": "49.95121990866204", 
        "longitude": "-117.861328125"
     },
     {
        "latitude": "-33.578014746143985", 
        "longitude": "-55.986328125"
     }
    ]  
}, 
"action"=>"create", 
"controller"=>"sets"
}
```

i.e. the "0" and "1" the error is referring to are like array indices.

Comment: still adding the keys, any ideas?

Comment: @WhomWhomWhom fixed, sorry for the confusion. Used [this](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters) as a reference.